# React - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently dove back into React after some months, and have been working on a Pokedex side project to familiarize myself again with the framework. I have been met with this message from React reading an undefined property from an API call. I have been able to access the other JSON data fine, but for some reason, when it comes to trying to pull one of the nested properties from "sprites", I receive the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'front_default')
    at PokemonPage (PokemonPage.js:30:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

I have been able to access this same information with no problem in another component, so not sure where I am going wrong. I spent some time googling possible solutions, but no luck yet with a resolution.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Code I am working with:

```
const PokemonPage = () => {

    const { id } = useParams();

    const [pokemonDetails, setPokemonDetails] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
      axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`,
        params: {id: id}
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        setPokemonDetails(res.data)
      })
    }, []);

  return (
    <div>
          <Card.Title style={{fontSize: '15px'}}>#{pokemonDetails.id} {pokemonDetails.name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title style={{fontSize: '15px'}}>{pokemonDetails.base_experience}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src={pokemonDetails.sprites.front_default} style={{width: '120px'}} />
  </div>
  )
}
```

[JSON Data I am trying to access (sprites information):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu3ld.png)

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: Note that is says "code, **data**, error messages, etc." Also, this is the standard "Accessing properties of objects before they are hydrated" problem. Add code that checks to make sure `pokemonDetails` and `pokemonDetails.sprites` are defined before trying to get `front_default` from it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey love the "Accessing properties of objects before they are hydrated" line! Definitely will help me remember in future instances I come across this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because in the first render pokemonDetails is an empty array([]), so when you try to access `pokemonDetails.sprites.front_default` you are trying to access `[].sprites.front_default`, see the example in the image below:

[image: Example]

Try to render when the pokemonDetails exists. As it not receives an array(receives an object) from response data, you can initialize it as `null` or `undefined` to make more sense than an array.

The example below will render pokemonDetails content only when it has data.

```
const PokemonPage = () => {

    const { id } = useParams();

    const [pokemonDetails, setPokemonDetails] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() => {
      axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}`,
        params: {id: id}
      }).then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        setPokemonDetails(res.data)
      })
    }, []);

  return (
    <div>
          {pokemonDetails ? (<Card.Title style={{fontSize: '15px'}}>#{pokemonDetails.id} {pokemonDetails.name}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Title style={{fontSize: '15px'}}>{pokemonDetails.base_experience}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src={pokemonDetails.sprites.front_default} style={{width: '120px'}} />) : <div>loading...</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! So this essentially will only render the data only when it is available from the API call. Thank you again for the insightful answer!

Answer (score 0):

because, when component will mount your state equal empty array. So, `[].sprites` equal `undefined` and  `undefined.front_default` you catch error with `Cannot read properties of undefined`

You can change your code to this

```
<Card.Img variant="top" src={pokemonDetails?.sprites?.front_default} style={{width: '120px'}} />
```